# Explicit usernames in references to objects

Tags: oracle, access-control

Much of our code -- both in external programs and in stored procedures -- uses explicit usernames, when referring to various DB-objects:

```sql
SELECT * FROM prod.object
```

or

```sql
prod.StoredProcedure(.....)
```

This causes obvious problem, when a copy of the database is loaded into a schema with a different name -- the same object becomes `qa.object` now...

I proposed, we drop such explicit references completely, referring simply to the `object` and `StoredProcedure` instead.

However, this would cause problems when *another account* (such as `prod_ro`) logs in and tries to execute `prod`'s stored procedures or browse `prod`'s tables.

How do people handle such situations?

Comment: Generally you would have a different database per environment, then you would have the same schemas but with different passwords. Keeping every environment in the same database means critical things like temp, memory and undo space are shared between prod and dev - a disaster waiting to happen. That said, you can use `alter session set current_schema=qa;` to change the default schema your object references refer to.

Comment: Aha, so any other account logging-in can `alter session` to set the default schema like that? Thanks! What's the equivalent OCCI call? Can you turn your comment into an answer, so I can "accept" it?

Comment: For OCI you would run it as a non query, like you would for a procedure or an insert (I don’t know the exact method off the top of my head).

Comment: You could create synonyms for required objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
alter session set current_schema=qa;
```

Then, all references to objects that aren’t qualified with a schema will be treated as if you wrote `qa.object`. You will still need the necessary privileges to work with the relevant object.

Comment: Thanks. Could I trouble you for the C++ and/or C-call to do the same?